# Dividing an even number in the most efficient way

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I need a program in c++ that gets a number:

LOOP:

If that number is even divide it by 2 (n=n/2)
If it's not even you can do one of this operations:
n+1
n-1

LOOP ENDS

---

The program should do this until n=1.
But it should do this in the most efficient and fastest way and the only hint I have is that I can use DP approach.
And the output should be numbers of operations used to calculate that number.
For example:

15->16->8->4->2->1       output:5

35->36->18->9->8->4->2->1    output:7

here's the code I wrote but it's not completed yet and it's wrong since I couldn't figure out how should I add or subtract in each step:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    int h=0;
    int i=0;
    cout<<"Enter A Number:";
    cin >> n;
    int r=n;
    int q=n;
    cout<<r;
    L1: while ( r % 2 == 0)
    {
        for(int m=0;r>1 && m==0 ;)
        {   r=r / 2;h++;
        m=r%2;
    cout<<" => "<<r;
        }}
    while(r%2==1 && r>1)
        {r=r-1;cout<<" => "<<r;h++;
    goto L1;}
    cout<<endl;

    //**********************


    cout<<q;
    L2: while ( q % 2 == 0)
    {
        for(int m=0;q>1 && m==0 ;)
        {   q=q / 2;i++;
        m=q%2;
    cout<<" => "<<q;
        }}
    while(q%2==1 && q>1)
        {q=q+1;cout<<" => "<<q;i++;
    goto L2;}
    cout<<endl<<"First:"<<h<<endl<<"Second:"<<i<<endl;
system("pause");


}
```

Comment: What have you been tried so far?

Comment: Interesting problem. But why don't you want to have a go yourself?

Comment: I would try to avoid applying the operations explicitly but instead finding a more direct way of calculating `f(n)` such that `f` is the number of operations needed. My first guess would be trying to find out how many steps are needed to get from `n` to a power of 2 (because from that point on it is trivial to get the number of steps)

Comment: @Prometheus I wrote something embarrasing I rather not show it :(

Comment: @Bathsheba each one that makes the calculation ends faster for example 35->36->18->9->8->4->2->1 is the right one but this one is not since it takes longer to reach 1.... 35->34->17->18->9->8->4->2->1

Comment: Well, you should. It is the right way for you to understand and solve your own questions with the help of SO users as it needs to be. So I would strongly suggest you to post your code too. @AliASEpicEXP

Comment: any code is less embarrasing than no code :P

Comment: @Prometheus sorry, you guys right I added the code

Comment: @Bathsheba I really like to do it myself I tried for last couple of days but couldn't figure it out :(

Comment: My guess would be some method that uses powers of two and tries to calculate your distance to a power of two or the nearest number that is the sum of the largest powers of two. If you look at the bitmasks of numbers, you'll start to see you want to achieve the longest run of consecutive zeroes possible so you can just keep dividing. I'm guessing the worst case numbers will have a bit pattern that just alternates 1's and 0's. Something like 1,431,655,765.

Comment: @tobi303 I added the code but didn't get your point man

Comment: once you reached a power of two, lets say 2^x, then you know already what is the minimum number of operations needed to get 1 ( it is just x). Based on this you also know what is the result for numbers that can be written as 2^x + 1 or 2^x -1, etc...

Comment: .. or did you mean the point of no code being more embarrassing than any code ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you **want to solve it using DP**:

I would state this: for each possible value 1 <=i < N find the optimal number of steps. 
We use a priority queue to do this where we extract at each iteration the highest number. This is much more efficient than a vector of length N because a lot of states are unreachable (e.g. i=10 in the 15 example).

Consider that the starting state is (15,0): 15 with zero moves.
From this you create two new states (8,2) and (7,2) because for each you need two steps(add/subtract + division).

Extracting (8,2): (7,2)(4,3)

Extracting (7,2): (4,3)(3,4)  Here comes DP! (7,2) would create the state (4,4) but you mantain in the queue only the minimum number of steps for the same state.

Extracting (4,3): (2,4)(3,4)

extracting(3,4): (2,4)(1,6)

Extracting (2,4): (1,5)

And that is it the solution is 5 steps.

Steps for 35:

(35,0) --- >(18,2) (17,2) -----> (17,2) (9,3) ----->

(9,3)(8,4) ----> (8,4)(5,5)(4,5) ----> (5,5)(4,5) ----->

(4,5)(3,7)(2,7)----> (3,7)(2,6) -----> (2,6)(1,9) ----> (1,7)

Solution: 7 steps.

Answer (score 0):

Look if that helps you.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int f (int n)
{
    int iterations = 0;

    while (n > 1)
    {
        if (n % 2 != 0)
        {
            std::cout << n << "->";
            ++n;
            if (n & (n - 1))
                n -= 2;

            ++iterations;
        }
        std::cout << n << "->";
        n >>= 1;
        ++iterations;
    }

    std::cout << n << "->";
    return iterations;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f(15) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f(41) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f(43) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty decent  algorithm wise.

Answer (score 0):

For use of dynamic programming, you should make recursion to get sub-solutions to the problem and then solve the problem itself. You also have to use a memory structure to hold the results of such sub-solutions.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int solve(deque<int>& solution, int number) {
    if(number >= solution.size())           // resize to fit
        solution.resize(number + 1, -1);
    if(number == 1)                         // special case for number 1
        return solution[number] = 0;
    if(solution[number] != -1)              // if already calculated
        return solution[number];
    if(number % 2 == 0)                     // n=n/2
        return solution[number] = solve(solution, number/2) + 1;
    int solutionA = solve(solution, number + 1);    // n++
    int solutionB = solve(solution, number - 1);    // n--
    return solution[number] = std::min(solutionA, solutionB) + 1; // best of n++,n--
}

int main() {
    deque<int> solution;
    cout << solve(solution, 35);
}
```

I'm not sure the code will work though.

Comment: I think the solution has to be smarter than this if using dynamic programming. This is likely to exhaust memory for any large values very quickly. It's a good way to brute for test an algorithm for correctness though.

Comment: Well, you can replace std::deque with std::map, it will conserve memory at the expense of speed and it will add some code bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my recursive solution, verified up to 2097152 against the DP example.
The basis of it is using the value of the last two bits to determine the optimal operation. If the last bit is a `0`, we always divide. If the last two bits are `11` we always increment as this transforms to `100` which enables two consecutive divide operations.
If the last two bits are `01` we decrement as this gives our next operation two consecutive divide operations vs incrementing which gives us `10`.

The corner case is the number 3 where 3 -> 2 is desired over promotion to 4.

I suspect you can optimise this further by just scanning the bit pattern to determine the number of operations required. i.e. each zero requires a div op, and a set of ones can be changed into zeroes with a single addition.

```
#include <cstdint>

int solve_algorithmically(std::uint64_t number)
{
    // If 1 there is nothing to do.
    if (number <= 1)
        return 0;

    // Nasty hack to get around the case where number=3 & 3 == 3 will cause increment 
    if (number == 3)
        return solve_algorithmically(number - 1) + 1;

    // If we have an even number (0 in LSB)
    if ((number & 1) == 0)
        return solve_algorithmically(number / 2) + 1;

    // If we have two consecutive 1's i.e. (...11) then increment as this wil give us two zeroes.
    // The exception is the root case 3 where decrement wins.
    if ((number & 3) == 3)
        return solve_algorithmically(number + 1) + 1;

    // The only other case ends last two bits = 01
    return solve_algorithmically(number - 1) + 1;
}

int main() {
    for (auto i = 1; i < 2097152; i++)
    {
        int alg = solve_algorithmically(i);
    }
}
```